# Upgrade pre-installed database with new data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to ship my app with pre-installed database, that contains table filled with data. Also I want to allow user to modify one column of this table (boolean isFavorite flag). Moreover, in future app updates I want to upgrade database with new data, but I want to keep user changes safe.

For this purposes I wanted to use https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper library. It handles database upgrade automatically using sql scripts. But it seems like it can only upgrade scheme of database, but unable to add new data. So I wondering if there is a solution which allows:

- Ship application with existing filled database storead as sqlite file in assets folder
- Upgrate database with new data as the application upgrades
- Upgrate database scheme as the application upgrades
- Retain user data (one column) during upgrade

I investigated multiple questions on SO, but haven't found the solution of upgrading database with new data.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can add new data to the database in sqlite-asset-helper upgrade scripts.

See for example the [sample script](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/samples/database-v2-upgrade/src/main/assets/databases/northwind.db_upgrade_1-2.sql) that does an `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the data from database version 1?